# Github API update json file

Tags: base64, github-api

I'm using the Github Contents API to update a `.json` file within a repo, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. This is a client-side (browser) request.

Basically, I have a `json` file and I would like to add a new `JSON` object to it. The structure of the object is

```js
id: ''
isEnabled: true
```

With the Contents API I am able to create the commit but it sort of looks like this -
[image]

This is the code that is responsible for creating and pushing the commit object

```js
let updatedContent = utf8.decode(base64.encode(modifiedContent));
    console.log(updatedContent);

    // const commit = await fetch(
    //   `${GITHUB_HOST}/repos/${OWNER}/${REPO}/contents/src/components.json`,
    //   {
    //     method: 'PUT',
    //     headers: AuthService.getAuthServiceInstance().withGithubAuthHeaders({
    //       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //     }),
    //     body: JSON.stringify({
    //       path: 'src/components.json',
    //       content: updatedContent,
    //       sha,
    //       message,
    //       branch: activeBranch,
    //     }),
    //   }
    // );
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrect in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `modifiedContent` is a valid JSON Object:

For NodeJS:

```
const updatedContent = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(modifiedContent), "utf8").toString("base64")
```

For Browser:

```
const updatedContent = btoa(JSON.stringify(content))
```

Then proceed to construct your request as you've shown above.

To use the API you've mentioned, you're code would look something like:

```
const originalContent = await getFromOrigin(...);

const modifiedContent = await getUpdatedContentFromEditor(...);

const updatedContent = btoa(modifiedContent);
```

**Edit 1**: Added the browser and NodeJS variants.
**Edit 2**: Added more context.

Comment: In the whole Internet there are only one question about this problem which I able to find. I have the same problem, I made a question on StackOverFlow too. Can you help me please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089860/github-api-uploading-json-file 

I need the same, but I'm still can't understand how to update the json file with your answer. Can you see my post and answer me there too if you understand. I try to do it many time already and I can't to implement still. Thanks!