# GitHub API uploading json file

Tags: github-api

I try to update my json file with GitHub API. I found some solution.

Need to make this POST request `https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/git/trees` with a body like this:

```
{
   "base_tree": "{{sha-base-tree}}",
    "tree": [
       {
           "path": "fil1.json",
           "mode": "100644",
           "type": "blob",
           "content": "updated text"
       }
    ]
}
```

But problem with a `content` variable. I can't pass a json type to this. If I try to pass a json like this  `{"files": [{"image": "link"}]}`:

```
{
   "base_tree": "{{sha-base-tree}}",
    "tree": [
       {
           "path": "fil1.json",
           "mode": "100644",
           "type": "blob",
           "content": "{"files": [{"image": "link"}]}"
       }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
{
   "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
   "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/git#create-a-tree"
}
```

I read the documentation and I found some `Custom media types for blobs` https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#custom-media-types-for-blobs Maybe it is my case, but I can't understand how to use it.

Can you help me how to update a json file with GitHub API programmatically?

Comment: `content` has to be a String, either `utf8` or `base64` encoded. Try with `content: JSON.stringify(content)`

Comment: @dezinezync Many thanks! It helped me. And also I want to say, this problem was with Postman. When I tried to code it, problem is gone.

Comment: I generally don't recommend using Postman. Use libcurl (or if you're on macOS, one of the many amazing native app GUIs)

Comment: @dezinezync why? I thought Postman is a good program. GUI allows make requests very fast.